# The upper bound of the definition interval of a maximal solution ($x'(t) = x(t)^3$)

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

We consider a Cauchy's problem : $x'(t) = x(t)^3$, $x(0)=a \in \mathbb{R}$.

I have to determine if the maximal solution is global (defined on $\mathbb{R}$) or not.

To begin,  I know $x^3$ is positive on $]0,+\infty[$ and negative on $]-\infty,0[$. The solution $u(t)=0$ is a constant solution. A non constant solution $u$ is strictly greater than $0$ or strictly less than $0$.

Let $u(t) > 0$. In this case, $u(t)$ is increasing on its definition interval $]T^-, T^+[$. Then, $u(t)$ is bounded lower by $0$. Then, $T^- = -\infty$.

Let $u(t) < 0$. In this case, $u(t)$ is decreasing on its definition interval $]T^-,T^+[$. In more $u(t)$ is bounded upper by $0$. Then, $T^- = -\infty$.

My question is : how to study this problem, in the two cases, for $T^+$ ? We have no enough informations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Osgood criterion](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Osgood_criterion) the life span of a solution of $x'(t)=x(t)^3$ only depends on the integrability of $g(z)=\frac{1}{z^3}$. The set of solutions is split in two components by the constant solution $x(t)=0$, and by assuming $x(0)=\alpha>0$ we have that the solution $x(t)$ is increasing, since $x'(t)>0$. We also have

$$ T=\int_{0}^{T}1\,dt=\int_{0}^{T}\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)^3}\,dt = \left[-\frac{1}{2 x(t)^2}\right]_{0}^{T} = \frac{1}{2\alpha^2}-\frac{1}{2x(T)^2}$$
hence:
$$ x(T) = \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{1-2\alpha^2 T}} $$
and any solution that starts with a positive value $x(0)$ only lives till the time $T=\frac{1}{2\alpha^2}$.
I leave to you to perform the analysis for negative times and for negative starting values.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$$\int \frac {x'}{x^3}=\frac {-1}{2x^2} =t+C$$